# In Laravel, "General error: 1364 Field 'xxx' doesn't have a default value" does not throw a QueryException or just an Exception

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I wish that laravel throw an exception on this "General error: 1364 Field 'author_id' doesn't have a default value" does not throw an exception instead this return the jsonresponse as expected if has succeeded... How can I have an Exception on this error ?

```
public function store(StageRequest $request): JsonResponse
    {
        $validatedData = $request->validated();

        $stage = new Stage();
        try {

            //Stage::create($validatedData);

            $stage->fill($validatedData);
            if ($stage->save()) {
                return response()->json([
                    'result' => 'success insert',
                    'id' => $validatedData['id'],
                ]);
            } else {
                return response()->json([
                    'result' => 'error',
                    'id' => $validatedData['id'],
                ]);
            }
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            report($e);
            return response()->json([
                'result' => 'error',
                'message' => $e->getMessage(),
                'id' => $request->input('id'),
            ]);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can catch **PDO Exception**, like  :

```
try
{
   //write your codes here
} 
catch(\PDOException $e)
{
   return response()->json([
        'result' => 'error',
        'message' => $e->getMessage(),
        'id' => $request->input('id'),
   ]);
}
```

Comment: nope it passes save() without throwing anything...  \Exception should have worked too.

Comment: Oh no it works, it's my fault I doesn't have parsed the response in order to see if there is an error, sorry !